# Inline SVG Element with Perfectly Positioned Overlay and Text On top

Tags: html, css, angularjs, svg

I have some inline SVG code that shows some circular icons, each with their own CSS styling (using fills and strokes), each icon in the SVG represents the progress of a user, there are 5 stages to this progress (it's an app built with Angular).

When the user is in any of the 5 possible states, the same corresponding icon in the SVG will have a circular outline with some opacity, basically an overlay. So if the user is in stage 3, for example, the stage 3 icon will have this circular overlay applied and also add some text on top of it (the stage name).

**I am having issues with the positioning of this circular overlay and the text of this active stage. I have tried adding this styling and text with the `<foreignObject>`tag, but when the browser is resized it falls out of proportion.**

I apply the active stage class that does the above by passing in a current stage value to the Angular Directive ng-class, like so:

```html
 <customtag ng-class="{
  'stage-one-active': stage_value === 1,
  'stage-two-active': stage_value === 2,
  'stage-three-active': stage_value === 3,
  'stage-four-active': stage_value === 4,
  'stage-five-active': stage_value === 5
  }">
</customtag>
```

The `customtag` contains the inline SVG. Whenever a user is in any of the stages, that class will be applied, and the troublesome circular overlay with text it will be applied.

***I am looking for ideas as to what would be a good way to add this overlay and text on top of a portion of an SVG inline image and that stays in place no matter the screen size.***

As always any valuable input is greatly appreciated it. Thanks.

```html
<svg version="1.1" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xml:space="preserve" 
    viewBox="0 0 1120 940">

    <!-- One Icon Example, there are 4 more like this one -->
    <g class="program-modeling-stage">
        <!-- This is my attempt, the overlay and text do not position correctly -->
        <foreignObject width="200" height="200" requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

            <div class="active-stage-overlay"><!-- This would be the circular overlay that sits on top of entire icon image -->
                <div class="active-stage-text">Current Stage</div><!-- This would be the text -->
            </div>
        </foreignObject>
       <!-- END attempt... -->
        <text class="stage-label" x="45" y="290">Business</text>
        <text class="stage-label" x="40" y="320">Development</text>

        <circle class="stage-diagram" cx="92" cy="432" r="87.5" />
        <g>
            <path class="stage-diagram-growth-background" d="M89.4,365,60.82,414.5h62.35L94.6,365A3,3,0,0,0,89.4,365Z" transform="translate(0 -1)" />
            <path class="stage-diagram-program-background" d="M60.82,414.5,32.24,464a3,3,0,0,0,2.6,4.5H149.16a3,3,0,0,0,2.6-4.5l-28.58-49.5Z" transform="translate(0 -1)" />
        </g>
        <path class="stage-diagram-growth-line" d="M92.9,409h18.05a1,1,0,0,0,.82-1.42l-8.21-14.21" transform="translate(0 -1)" />
        <line class="stage-diagram-program-line" x1="42.86" y1="460.48" x2="82.86" y2="460.48" />
        <g>
            <path class="stage-diagram-collective-on" d="M182.5,425.83A90.8,90.8,0,0,0,99.17,342.5" transform="translate(0 -1)" />
            <path class="stage-diagram-collective-on" d="M99.17,523.5a90.57,90.57,0,0,0,83.33-83.09" transform="translate(0 -1)" />
            <path class="stage-diagram-collective-on" d="M1.5,440.17A90.57,90.57,0,0,0,84.59,523.5" transform="translate(0 -1)" />
            <path class="stage-diagram-collective-on" d="M84.59,342.74A90.34,90.34,0,0,0,1.5,425.83" transform="translate(0 -1)" />
        </g>
        
    </g>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Help us to help you. Please post an [MCVE].

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thanks Paul, done. Pls note that's just one icon but the rest are exactly the same (there are 5 total), which are all one in one big <svg> element.

Comment: I meant a full example with angular and your custom tage etc. Although as minimal as you can.

Comment: Why are you trying to position HTML in and SVG instead of the other way round?

Comment: Because everything is inline SVG, and also in a directive <custom-angular-directive>, all there is an SVG element, nothing else, hence my issue hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually really simple to solve and not that big a deal (sigh).

What I did was give the SVG element a fixed width and kept the same approach of using foreignObject. I applied CSS classes to the DIVs inside foreignObject that have absolute positioning and everything positions correctly.

The only issue is that I have to reposition the values for screen sizes that fall below the fixed width I set in place.

```css
#progression-diagram {
  svg {
    width: 600px;
  }
  
  .active-stage-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: transparentize($primary-color, 1);
    transition: background-color 700ms ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .active-stage-label {
    fill: $primary-color;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<foreignObject x="279" y="566" width="200" height="200">
  <div class="active-stage-overlay">
    <div class="active-stage-label">Current Stage</div>
  </div>
</foreignObject>
```